# What is the component inside TextFields in JavaFX?

Tags: java, css, javafx

I have an app in JavaFX that has both generic Panes in them and TextFields. I want the Panes to have a visible border, and since the background of everything in this app is black, I only really need to change the color of any of the borders I want to actually see. To do this, in my stylesheet, I just go ahead and declare:

```
Pane {
    -fx-background-color: black;
    -fx-border-color: red;
}
```

Red for effect here in the following image.

Now, the problem is that this messes with my TextFields. I have changed the color of the borders of the TextFields to green so that they are visible in contrast to the Pane borders. The result is this:

```
.text-field {
    -fx-background-color: black;
    -fx-border-color: green;
}
```

There's other junk, but this is the relevant stuff.

[image: There are panes in my textfields.]

From the image, you can see the problem. There are panes inside of textfields, so by setting the border of the panes to red, I get an outline around the text inside the textfields that I don't want there. However, the reference guide or source code don't seem to demonstrate textfield having any internal components like that whatsoever, so since I don't know what specific kind of pane it is inside .text-field, I can't add a rule to my stylesheet to make it go away. How do I get rid of this thing?

Comment: Use [ScenicView](https://github.com/JonathanGiles/scenic-view) if you want to understand the structure of the scene graph.

Answer (score 4):

When you have this:

```css
Pane {
    /* ... */
}
```

Then you are using a "type selector". Any and all nodes that have a [type selector](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#getTypeSelector()) equal to `"Pane"` will be targeted by this CSS. In practice, that means all instances of `Pane` (but not subtypes) in the part of the scene graph covered by the stylesheet. This is likely undesirable.

I recommend you use a class selector:

```css
.some-pane-class {
    /* ... */
}
```

Or an ID selector:

```css
#somePaneId {
    /* ... */
}
```

This will involve [adding style classes](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#getStyleClass()) to nodes, if the node doesn't already have the desired style class, and/or [setting the ID](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#setId(java.lang.String)) of nodes. See the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#intro) for more information.

All that said, neither the Javadoc of JavaFX nor the CSS reference guide documents the entire structure of every control. Quite a bit of these structures are implementation details. And many of these undocumented nodes have no style class or ID. That's typically okay because it's rare you'll want to target these unknown nodes directly in a stylesheet. However, if you want to know the structure of the scene graph, including the undocumented parts, then two tools can help with that.

1. The *CSS Analyzer* view of [Scene Builder](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/).
2. And especially [Scenic View](https://github.com/JonathanGiles/scenic-view).

Additionally, you can study the [JavaFX source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx).

In the case of the default skin of `TextField`, there is a ["text group" pane](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/1b71f5b63e8afa2575e0bde6d0a42ecb2e0ecde8/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/skin/TextFieldSkin.java#L86) used to group the text, caret, and selection rectangle (at least in JavaFX 21). That is likely the `Pane` you see being styled in your question. Using a class selector or an ID selector, instead of a type selector, will solve the problem.